# Passing a new object as parameter to a function changing only 1 value

Tags: javascript, object, typescript

I have a function that takes an object as parameter. The object has a default value containing many properties and methods which I don't know. I however know one of the properties and I want to pass the default object with the property changed. How do I do it? for eg..

```js
class DataFactory() {
  private static getData(data) {} // data is an object having default set properties
}

// Somewhere in my other module

function blabla() {
  let name = 'Hello'
  let newData = DataFactory.getData(changedObj)
  //.... other stuffs
}

// here the changedObj is the default object with only the property called 'name' modified.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
changedObj = Object.assign({},changedObj, {name: 'new name'});
```

Or

```
changedObj['name'] = 'New Name';
```

Comment: In this case, won't the *changedObj* only have a single property and not the other properties of the default *data* object that I want to pass? Will this merge the *changedObj* into *data* object and pass *data* object to the function? thank you :)

Comment: @Jamie [Object.assign docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: consider using `changedObj = {...changedObj, name: 'new name'};` which is much cleaner and does not require a dummy object to prevent mutation